# What position does this describe?

Tags: jobs

Your tasks include concept, visual design and the HTML/ CSS/ JavaScript implementation of complex screen interfaces. We are looking for creativity with a keen sense for aesthetics and graphical innovation...

Answer (score 2):

I would call this kind of position a "Web Designer".  From my research looking for UX positions, I've come to expect this ontology:

- Visual Designer = visual design without implementation
- UI Designer = Visual Designer
- UX/UI Designer = Visual Designer
- UX Designer = experience design and research with or without visual design
- Interaction Designer = experience design and research without visual design
- Interactive Designer = (I honestly haven't seen a consistent use of this title)
- Web Designer = visual design with implementation
- Front-end Developer = implementation only
- UX Developer = Front-end Developer

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're describing a hybrid of:

**Interactive designer/Front end developer**

Somebody to create wireframes (eg: Basamiq), designs (eg: Photoshop) and then create front end templates (HTML/CSS/JS).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a combination web designer and web presentation layer developer. They exist, though often you'll have that as two separate roles.